# Gridview.builder with Sticky headers

Tags: flutter

I am hella frustrated.

I need a Gridview.builder (or Listview with 3 Columns in each row)
AND on top of the Grid I need 1 Header.

Yet my code screws either the 3 Column List up, or the Header which will be tripled then.

I am a total coding newbie. Yet I am trying desperately to fix this issue.

Sorry for the wrong code in advance.

```
GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate:
        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,),
        itemCount: 210,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return StickyHeader(
        header: Container(
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text('Header',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        content: Column(
          children:
          List<int>.generate(21, (index) => index)
              .map((item) => Container(
            decoration:
            BoxDecoration( //                    <-- BoxDecoration
                border: Border(bottom: BorderSide())
            ),
            height: 50,
            width: 5000000,
            child: Text ('Test'),

          ))
              .toList(),
          ),
        );

        }),
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Column` which first child is the header and the second one is the `GridView` inside an `Expanded` widget.

Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/csbence10/ba1ccab88c008b1daa28a0be7eb4d7f1).

Or you can use slivers in a `CustomScrollView`. Short tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM).